# Why RESTfull API request to view return 404 in Yii2?

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2

I adjusted module api, and created controller UserController extends ActiveController. All work fine, but view return 404 error.

- http://example.com/api/user/45 – return 404 (Error)
- http://example.com/api/user/view/?id=45 - return 200 (Ok)

Why yii\rest\UrlRule don't work in this case?

Info from official page about this rule:

```
GET /users/123: return the details of the user 123;
```

**ANSWER**:

1. Set yii\rest\UrlRule::$pluralize property to false;
2. Set enableStrictParsing to false.

Comment: It may help to attach your actual code that implements `UserController` and perhaps describe your configuration in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Be sure to have the same configs as shown in related [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html#configuring-url-rules):

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'user'],
    ],
]
```

2- Enabling Pretty Url in Yii requires further configurations at server level. For example if server is *apache* a similar configs to those should be added to *htaccess* file:

```
# Set document root to be "basic/web"
DocumentRoot "path/to/basic/web"

<Directory "path/to/basic/web">
    # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
    RewriteEngine on
    # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php

    # ...other settings...
</Directory>
```

More details and related configs to *nginx* can be found in the [getting started section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#recommended-apache-configuration). Also check those tutorials for *basic* and *advanced* templates:

- https://www.diggin-data.de/dd-cms/blog/post/view/id/1004/name/Creating+a+REST+API+for+Yii2-basic-template
- http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/

3- Depending on the project structure there is cases where you'll need to use *RewriteBase* or equivalent to define the base path holding your app. Like adding this to an *apache*'s *htaccess* file:

```
RewriteBase /backend/api
```

4- From the [rest quick start guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html):

> Yii will automatically pluralize controller names for use in endpoints. You can configure this using the
>   [yii\rest\UrlRule::$pluralize](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html#$pluralize-detail) property.

Which means endpoint url is expected to look like *http://example.com/api/users/45* by default.

Comment: This is all right. And rules ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'user'] also have.

Comment: thank you, It helped me. But but I also set enableStrictParsing = false.