# Yii2 Web Service not returning a single row from database

Tags: web-services, yii2

I've made a web service using yii2 basic template I got a table called 'ely_usuario' when I call it with:

http://localhost/basic/web/index.php/ely-usuario/

it works fine and returns me all the rows in ely_usuario table

but when I try to get just one record, for example:

http://localhost/basic/web/index.php/ely-usuario/29

it doesn't work, show me a not found page, I've made the model class using gii

here's my Controller:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class ElyUsuarioController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\ElyUsuario';
}
```

My configs:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'ely-usuario'],
            ],
        ],
```

Another weird thing that you might noticed is that 'enableStrictParsing' is false, in the yii2 guide it says to be true but for me it only works with false

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code in your configs.I hope you will get an idea from the following code.It works fine for me!

```
'urlManager' => [
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
'showScriptName' => false,
'rules' => [
'<controller:(ely-usuario)>/<action>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
],
],
```

And in your controller please check your specific action.It must be coded like as:

```
public function actionTransactions($id=null){
if($id!=null){
//retrieve single row
}else{
 //retrieve multiple rows
}
```

Also please check this link for reference:

[Why RESTfull API request to view return 404 in Yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122081/why-restfull-api-request-to-view-return-404-in-yii2?rq=1)

I hope it helps!

Comment: So should I create an action to retrive a single row ?

Comment: I have edited my answer.If still it doesn't seem fruitful please create other action where you will get your request as :
$id = (int) Yii::$app->request->get('id');